# Fetch a Google Drive document title; URL only is available

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-drive-api, integration

My application displays Google Drive document details as user entered URLs (like
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Af3Lf_RNxlzDhW3...). I want to programmatically fetch the title of that document, if available, and display it along with the URL. That will help user to distinguish between similarly looking hash strings containing links.

By title I mean what the creator/editor name the resource.

I am looking at both client side and server side options. The client side seems to be the right place to perform this operation, as in my scenario the client normally has access to a resource by the link. So, asking Google for extra details OR load the resource into frame and parse OR etc seems to make sense to perform on the client.

Comment: Google documents need to be published to the web in order to do that (File > Publish to the web)

Comment: @JeremyThille and after that is done, what kind of scripting work has to be performed to obtain the title?

Comment: Give it a go. I just tried it. I published a test document, then opened the published link in a new tab. From there on, grabbing the title is super easy, it has an ID=`#header`. It's really basic stuff, I don't want to give you the full solution ;)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I don't see any solution in your words though. Making document public is not an option in my scenario.

Comment: But if you don't want to publish your document, it can't be accessed, so I don't know how you possibly could grab its title...